# Best way to convert code containing Date objects to Firebase.Timestamp objects when using toObject method to convert Snapshot to POJOs

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, java.util.date

I noticed that I have been getting the below **warning**, every-time I am running my app code:

> W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: The behavior for java.util.Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
>       To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
    .build();
firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as com.google.firebase.Timestamp objects instead of as system java.util.Date objects. So you will also need to update code expecting a java.util.Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:

```
// Old:
java.util.Date date = snapshot.getDate("created_at");
// New:
Timestamp timestamp = snapshot.getTimestamp("created_at");
java.util.Date date = timestamp.toDate();
```

> Please audit all existing usages of java.util.Date when you enable the new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

The example provided with the warning suggests the best way to convert the code if you are fetching each document object individually from the DocumentSnapshot.

**My question** here is - what if you are using `.toObject()` method on the DocumentSnapshot to obtain POJO directly from it, is there a suggested/optimized way of updating the code/data model in this scenario?

Because of the following scenarios `java.util.Date` has been used in the app currently -

1. Since there are many places the date object is being used throughout the app.
2. Also Date is value for a few Map data type objects (eg. `Map<String, Date>`). How to handle code conversion for this type of data objects in documentSnapshot with not too many major changes?

> One way I have already thought is to update the POJO's with `java.util.Date` fields to `com.google.firebase.Timestamp` as well as in the `Map<K, V>` implementations. After that update the code implementation by adding `.toDate()` after the Timestamp field calls. **But this way doesn't seem optimized**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK will automatically convert Timestamp document fields into Date objects for POJO class members when using toObject().  It's able to detect the type at runtime to make the conversion.

The warning you're citing is for code that attempts to assume the type of an object when accessing the snapshot data directly.

Comment: hi Doug, any example demonstrating the same? i am trying to store the user selected date as Date object being passed via POJO. the date is getting stored as map with seconds and nanoseconds. when retrieving , i am getting deserializing error